# Creating a PHPExcel writer

Tags: php, phpexcel

In various tutorials on PHPExcel there are two ways that are used to create a writer:

`$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($document);`

and

`$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($document, 'Excel2007');`

What is the difference between these two statements?

Answer (score 1):

The static utility class has an internal procedure to supply different types/implementations of the writer, as an override or an addition, whereas directly creating an instance of the "stock" writer using the `new` keyword will always, of course, give you an instance of the specific class you have in the code.

Using the factory will allow you to override the writer project-wide without having to modify the individual spots in the code where the instance is created.

A look at the code is useful to understanding:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php#L129

It's worth noting, however, that care should be taken with static factories like this -- it can create hidden dependencies in your code.